# My postgresql db dump is 500mb, even though I've nuked every single table

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

I was at some point storing files in my database (Spring JPA Lob, Byte[]), and then I moved them to the file system, however the size of the database never decreased after dropping thee old columns. I'm investigating again now and I've deleted -ALL- the tables, and yet it is still 500mb. In the dump file I can see there is some giant LOB/s it is writing, but I don't know how to get rid of this 'ghost' data or even see it in the DB using psql or another tool. Any ideas?
Using Postgresql 12 on Ubuntu.

Comment: If you're already deleting all the data, why not drop the database and start fresh?

Comment: Deleting the data is part of diagnosis to see where the space was trapped, so I dropped table by table.. I could start afresh, but that would require an export import script to be written, which I'd rather not have to do.